# How to ignore missing dll error in Windows

Tags: error-handling, dll, exe

I have this wireless mouse software/driver that is designed to run on Windows 8 and later versions, that I want to run on Windows 7 machine.
The software is using Bluetoothapis.dll for the bluetooth functionality, which is not available in Windows 7 and this is preventing the program from running with a missing dll error. I have opened the exe file in hex editor and yes, there is a bunch of BluetoothGATT calls.
I tried manually adding Bluetoothapis.dll and all the dependent dll-s to the installation folder, but it ends up with a DEVOBJ.dll error and I don't want to mess with that one.
Is there a way to ignore the missing dll error via Windows and run the program anyway or something I can do to the exe file itself? I am using the mouse in 2.4 GHz or wired mode so I don't care about bluetooth connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

The .dll contains a compiled program, and it's binary. You cannot alter its contents. To alter its contents, you'd need the source code.

Lets just also say that, if this was easy, then Microsoft would have, possibly, provided the solution. Likely Windows 7 misses a lot more than what you've mentioned.

The solution would therefore be to upgrade your OS.